# Minecraft Tools Not Having Texture And Not Showing Up?

Tags: minecraft

For some reason, my 1.16.5 modding server does not have netherite axes? They show the description and name, but no item. When I hold the axe, I can see it in my hand. This is also for some armor, etc. I was wondering why this was?

Comment: It's on non-servers as well, I'm assuming it's a problem with my PC?

Comment: it seems to be your texture pack or just your game that his broken. Check if you are alone to have this. Finally, it's not on the good side, it have to be on [Arqade/Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)